# How to use Alarmmanager To trigger a Broadcast receiver?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I am a newbie Android and I am developing an app in which I want to toast a message after every 5 minutes. I am using a Broadcast Receiver for this. I want to use an Alarmmanager to trigger the Broadcast receiver.I want this app to run in the background only.
can anyone suggest me step by step what to do? My codes are as follow:

```
     public class k extends BroadcastReceiver{

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


     Toast.makeText(context, "in android.location.PROVIDERS_CHANGED",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Intent broadcast = new Intent(context, k.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, broadcast, 0);

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.setRepeating(getResultCode(), 1000,10, pendingIntent);
     Toast.makeText(context, "in android.location.PROVIDERS_CHANGED",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
```

}

Comment: **1.** What is `getResultCode()`? This argument needs to be one of the types specified by AlarmManager: ELAPSED_REALTIME, ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, RTC, or RTC_WAKEUP. **2.** The value 1000 is wrong. You need to get the value of a time somewhere in the future. Depending on which alarm type you choose (see #1), you would start either with `System.currentTimeMillis()` or `SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()` or something derived from a `Date` or `Calendar` object. **3.** You are using 10 milliseconds as the repeat interval, which is far too short.

Answer (score 1):

```
Intent broadcast = new Intent(context, gpsbroad.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, broadcast, 0);

AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager.setExact(alarmType, triggerAtMillis, pendingIntent);
```

PendingIntent: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html

AlarmManager: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html

Answer (score 0):

try to use this:

```
public static AlarmManager am;
public static PendingIntent sender;


Intent intent1 = new Intent(thisActivity, gpsbroad.class);
sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(thisActivity, 2, intent1,0);
am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
long l = new Date().getTime();
if (l < new Date().getTime()) {
    l += 100;
}
am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, l, 100, sender);
```

Comment: I dont want to start any activity..I just want to display a toast everythime the time changes. Pls check my editted code

Comment: add new activity and in it to display toast as below:
public class AlarmReciever extends BroadcastReceiver {
 @Override
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
  Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm Triggered", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 }
}

Comment: I just want it to run in the background because the app that I am developing requires it to run only in the background when it is installed